# How can I use ScrollView and AbsoluteLayout in one xml?

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, absolutelayout

I have a problem to include lots of pictures and buttons in the xml, I have tried to ScrollView but pictures and buttons can not be made ​​up as I wanted.

How can i use ScrollView and AbsoluteLayout in one xml so I can include more pictures and buttons in the xml?

Comment: paste the layout code in the question

Comment: Never use AbsoluteLayout at all, it's deprecated for a reason. You will run into trouble on many devices.

Comment: never use AbsoluteLayout for design android app, it is not reliable in android ok, and past ur design layouts here so we can give some solution right?

Comment: so how can I add more buttons and an image if the screen is full xml?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

NEVER use AbsoluteLayout! Instead try and recreate your layout using a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`.

Remember a `ScrollView` can only have a single Child layout, so use a `ViewGroup` here.

Comment: Sorry I dont follow. What do you need to see?

Comment: so how can I add more buttons and an image if the screen is full xml? is it impossible?

Comment: Your layout will have the following logic: ScrollView -> LinearLayout-> TextView. Place your views inside the LinearLayout. This is a simple layout question, which can be answered by viewing the Android Samples